# False name? Patient::Diagnosi

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to models:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :bis_gultigkeit, :geburtsdatum, :krankenkassennummer, :kvbereich, :landercode, :name, :namenszusatz, :plz, :statuserganzung, :strasse, :titel, :versichertennumer, :versichertenstatus, :vorname, :wohnort, :geschlecht, :telefon, :email, :gewicht
   has_many :diagnosis
end

class Diagnose < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :beschreibung, :code, :seite, :sicherheit, :typ, :patient_id
   belongs_to :patient
end
```

How you can see the two models have an association.
So that i want to display on the patient show page all of his diagnosis.

```
def show
 @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
 @diagnosis = @patient.diagnosis

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @patient }
 end
end
```

And in my view i call:

```
<%= @diagnosis.inspect %>
```

But somehow i get the error:

```
uninitialized constant Patient::Diagnosi
```

I cannot explain me why i get this error? And why does it say Diagnosi? I mean my model name is Diagnose! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call Diagnose.class_name.pluralize to see how rails pluralizes it.
I guess it is "Diagnoses", so you shoudl call:

```
@diagnoses = @patient.diagnoses
```

and

```
<%= @diagnoses.inspect %>
```